# How do you fix loading plugins in eclipse 3.5.1 on linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have two linux boxes.  Both Fedora 11 x64.

On one, I downloaded the eclipse-java-galileo-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz.  I unpacked it to /opt/eclipse-3.5.1/ and used the Install New Software... item to install the SVN team provider and the Polarion SVN connectors.  Everything works.

On the second, I copied the tar.gar for eclipse there, and then tried to follow the same steps.  When I get to the install SVN team provided, eclipse downloads it and claims to install it and asks to restart.  I restart and there is no SVN support.  The software installer knows its there because I can't reinstall it without uninstalling it.

So the questions: Why isn't the plugin/feature loading for the SVN Team Support?  Is there a checkbox that I forgot about that enables the plugin?  Is there a command line option that will force reload all of the features on the disk?   I've tried to install other things like findbugs, but I get the same result.

I have no messages in the log file indicating an exception or anything like that.

Comment: Have your second box had an existing eclispe installation ? I've had same problems on windows, updating broke Subclipse. Only way yo get it back was to erase te eclipse installation and the .eclipse in the homedir. Reinstall and update eclipse, THEN install the svn plugin.

Comment: In both cases they used to have 3.4.2 and then 3.5 and now 3.5.1.  The first box always worked and the second only had trouble from 3.5 to 3.5.1.

Comment: I have the same troubles with Eclipse 3.5.1 (installed in `/opt`) and plugins on GNU/Linux. Deleting `~/.eclipse` helped to install one plugin but installing another one broke everything again (eclipse couldn't see any plugin anymore). So it was very temporary. There must be a problem with this release...

Comment: But my other machine works just fine.  I've had no trouble with it so I've got to think its a configuration issue somewhere.

Comment: Installed in `/opt` too or in a user directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around the issue.

Select `Install New Software...`

In the dialog that pops up, Uncheck the box labeled `Contact all update sites during install to find required software`

Then proceed with the installation of findbugs, subversive connectors, and the SVN team provider.

When I didn't uncheck that box, the updater always installed a small collection of Mylyn plugins that are already installed.  Then, no plugins that were installed apart from what was part of the initial install would work.

EDIT:  Apparently I'm not alone with this trouble.  If I can find the bugreport, I'll add the link, but here is a [discussion in an eclipse forum](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg29591.html).

Comment: Hmm... So Mylin could be faulty here? Very interesting. I'll try this too. Thanks.