# SVN not working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

One day I pressed in Eclipse `Help` -> `Check for Updates` (and I learnt that I should Never Ever update a software which works fine.)

Then in a project that I used with SVN the whole submenu of "Team" and the little icons that showed that some files weren't commited, they all dissapeared.

I tried everything:

- revert from `Instalation History` tab
- uninstall from `Installed Software` tab
- replaced the folder `eclipse` in `Program Files` with a new one downloaded from eclipse website and tried to install again
- searched how to install it on the net

But in none of the cases above if I press <kbd>Ctrl+N</kbd> There is no SVN group;
If i right click on a project and select `Team` -> `Share project`, a window with CVS appears, but no SVN.
If I choose `File` -> `Import` I can't find SVN anywhere.

If I go to `Help` -> `About Eclipse` -> `Instalation details` I see at `Instalation History` in 25.06.2009, 09:59:08 GMT+03:00 (when SVN worked)

```
Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers  1.2.0.20090621-0820
Subclipse (Required)    1.6.2
Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter (Required) 1.6.3
SVNKit Library  1.3.0.5847
```

In the `Installed Software` tab I have now installed

```
Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers  1.2.0.20090621-0820 epp.package.jee
Subclipse (Required)    1.6.5   org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.feature.group
Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter (Required) 1.6.6   org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.feature.feature.group
SVNKit Library  1.3.1.6109  org.tmatesoft.svnkit.feature.group
```

How can I make SVN to work?
Where does eclipse store its files, because when I changed the eclipse directory with a new one all my stuff was there (the ones that I installed with no success: SVN, Subversive, Subclipse, SVNKit, ...)

Comment: I have had similar problems with SVN when the subversion client installed locally mismatches the version installed on the server.  However, I dont know enough about Eclipse plugins to know whether they integrate the SVN client libraries or call a SVN client you have installed independently on your PC.  If the later, and if they were updated, look into rolling that back.

Comment: It gives me an error when I try to `Revert` to a time that it worked.

Comment: The error is 'Revert configuration' has encountered a problem.

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
  session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.sun.jna,3.0.9
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.sun.jna,3.0.9
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.ide.capabilities,3.2.0.v20090429-0837
(and other 10 lines)

Comment: +1 for "and I learnt that I should Never Ever update a software which works fine," true enough with Eclipse!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive) is my favorite SVN implementation in Eclipse because it works better than the others and it integrates neatly into the UI.

I suggest you follow these steps:

1. [Download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) the most recent version of Eclipse (currently Galileo) and extract it to your desired installation location

   - Prior to running Eclipse, make sure you delete (or rename/relocate) your default workspace (under Windows this is `workspace` in your user directory)
   - Install the Subversive SVN Team Provider (as instructed by the [Eclipse incubation website](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive)) using Eclipse's software installer:
   - Choose `Help`, then `Install New Software...`
   - Create a new download location and specify the following download URL: `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo`
   - Locate **Collaboration**, expand it, then check **Subversive SVN Team Provider (Incubation)**
   - Proceed through the installation and accept the TOS
   - Restart Eclipse and Subversive should prompt you to select a SVN Connector. Reading the symptoms you describe, it sounds like you don't have a connector installed, or it isn't communicating with your team provider. The [Polarion website](http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/connector_discovery.php) has a guide for choosing the connector best suited for you.

If you aren't prompted to install a connector, you can always do so from the preferences screen:

[image: SVN preferences in Eclipse]

If the above doesn't work for you, it seems that your workspace isn't cleaned out. Locate your *default* workspace and try getting things working without any projects before you continue.

You could then also try deleting the `.eclipse` directory in your user directory. And starting over from step 3.

Comment: Bear in mind that if no `SVN` subitem appears under `Team` in the preferences screen, Subversive didn't install properly for some reason.

Comment: Finally, it works! But I got an error when I selected a connector from the  window with connector discovery (step 4). And I installed through `Install new software` and unchecked the option as Jay R. said.

Comment: Well, so much for "working better than the others". Subversive just broke here as well. Indeed unchecking `Contact all update sites during install to find required software` allowed me to finally get it installed again.

Answer (score 5):

The problem I had was that svn icons where not showing in the package explorer.

The solution for me was to **delete the .metadata folder in the workspace folder** (which will reset all your workspace including preferences and repository configurations)

After that all the icons appeared.

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue when SVN connector was not able to connect SVN repository in Eclipse.

Then, I do the following step's :-

- Right click on Project under Eclipse.
- Go to Team -> share Project.

It's working :)

Comment: Yeah, or remove and add again all projects.

Answer (score 3):

I found a problem related to installing plugins [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703753/how-do-you-fix-loading-plugins-in-eclipse-3-5-1-on-linux).  I also could not get the SVN stuff to show up in the preferences because of some bug with the software updater updating the Mylin plugins.   You'll likely have to get your Eclipse installation straightened out first and you can do this by just using a new workspace. You don't have to blow away the .metadata folder if you point Eclipse temporarily at a new workspace folder.  When the Eclipse installation is clean, you can start installing plugins again, but make sure to uncheck the box labeled `Contact all update sites during install to find required software`

Eclipse uses local SVN libraries that are part of an installed plugin for SVN support, be it SVNkit or JavaHL.  Netbeans uses SVN libraries that are installed independently.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this happen before with Eclipse and the various SVN plugins that it supports. The SVN plugin, for some reason, sometimes looses the SVN connection. Your best bet is to simply delete the project and re-check it out of svn. If you have changes that need to be committed you can use the command line.

Another problem you may have is that your plugin and your repository are out of sync in terms of version numbers. I have had problems before using a plugin designed for svn 1.6.x and a repository that was still at svn 1.4 or 1.5.

Comment: It is not connected because it disapeeared. I cannot check it out. because I can't reconnect. If I press Team -> Share project to a new project, I don't have the SVN option.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete all projects from eclipse and Re-Import the all projects again.
It is working for me.
Just try it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely start over with eclipse, you need to delete your workspace as well (the path you see when you first start eclipse).  Just re-installing the eclipse files and pointing to the same default workspace will not change anything for you.

Your best bet is to remove eclipse and your workspace and start over because you probably inadvertently broke some other parts of the plug in while you were trying to fix your initial problem.

Comment: 1) I deleted the folder  `.metadata` from my workspace and `RemoteSystemsTempFiles`  
2) I also 'deleted' (renamed) my old workspace, and when I start eclipse, it creates a new folder with the same name.  
Eclipse still remembers my instalation history.

Comment: eclipse remembers the *default* workspace location, did you try moving the location of your workspace folder?

Comment: If I rename it isn't just like I would have moved it? because it will not find the path.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you install everything as it is said, Subversive and SVN Connector (svnkit 1.x.x), in the project you may not see svn working. In my case I had to remove the project from workspace and import it again. Then it appears. (Refresh, clean did not worked).