# Eclipse to play nice wtih SVN version control and WAMP development environment

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, wamp

I've been using a WAMP stack for a while now and have my projects organized in this way

```
wamp/www/project1
wamp/www/project2
wamp/www/project3
etc.
```

Now I started to use Eclipse for PHP and have a workspace that's located in my C drive at

```
C:/my_eclipse_workspace
```

When I create new project in eclipse, a folder gets created for it at

```
C:/my_eclipse_workspace/project1
```

Then on top of that I need to start using a local version control repository on my system. All this is getting me scratching my head. How do I use Eclipse + have my project files in their appropriate wamp directory (e.g. wamp/www/project1 so they can launched easily from within the browser like I normally do) all while keeping the project somewhere under SVN? This may be simple and I'm just not getting it, so a detailed slow answer for the stupid would be much appreciated here.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply specify `wamp/www` as your Eclipse workspace. Note that this will add a `.metadata` directory inside the workspace path, containing plugin settings and a lock file (to make sure other instances don't interfere with your workspace).

As for SVN, simply take a look at [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive). There are others, such as Subclipse, but Subversive is in the Eclipse incubation and can be downloaded from the Galileo software site. For instructions on how to install it, see [my answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798468/svn-not-working-in-eclipse/1810442#1810442).