# No project showing up in project explorer in Eclispe for project created on separate computer and shared through SVN

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I have a project in an SVN folder like so
SVN/Android/Project/WorkingDir/Project

When committing, I think I added all of the metadata folder to the ignore list.  I then set up SVN etc. on another computer and opened up the same workspace "WorkingDir", but nothing showed up in the Project Explorer.

I checked the filter settings etc., I tried importing the preferences from the first workspace, I tried going into Import Exisitng projects (but it didn't recognize anything in the folder, even though the project is right there).

I've looked through StackOverflow and came across similar questions like the ones below, but none seem to help me

[Android+Eclipse project sharing via SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166947/androideclipse-project-sharing-via-svn)

Do I need to use "Subversive"
e.g. [SVN not working in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798468/svn-not-working-in-eclipse)

Perhaps .classpath, .project need to be added to the repository?  Looks like they currently aren't.
Via: [Why "no projects found to import"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638016/why-no-projects-found-to-import)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, syncing the .classpath and .project and project.properties files seemed to help.

Also I had the explorer filters messed up, so even then nothing was showing up, but I think the .classpath and .project were still necessary to get things to show up.  Not sure about properties though.

Then I had this problem [Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637144/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0-or-6-0-found-1-7-instead-plea) and solution there helped.