# eclipse 3.5.1 (Galileo) with ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic) busted! Can not install maven2 plugin! (Or any other plugin)

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, eclipse-plugin, ubuntu-9.10

I see a lot of stuff online related to fixing buttons that can't be pressed, and fixing network issues with proxies.  This seems like a different problem to me, related to jem.util.0.0.0 in the case of maven2 or needed libs for other plugins.

The setup:

Eclipse 3.5.1 (Galileo) installed with apt-get.
Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic Koala) (This is running as a VM, not that is should matter.)

General problem description:
Maven2 eclipse plugin installation fails.

Specifically, I can not install maven2 plugin from the eclipse installation flow using this target site:
http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e/

The maven site is found, installation begins, and then returns this error:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required) 0.10.0.20100209-0800\
 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.10.0.20100209-0800)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required) 0.10.0.20100209-0800 (org\
.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.10.0.20100209-0800) requires 'org.eclipse.jem.\
util 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Official Ubuntu documentation claims eclipse 3.5.1 support, and recommends using the Synaptic Package Manager, and nothing else about any issues.

Does anyone has any insight into this?

Comment: I did have the exact same problem: I will test this in a few hours and get back to you.

Comment: Installation done, and answer added.

Answer (score 5):

I manage to install it, but you need to be sure you do not validate just the m2eclipse site, but also the Galileo or Helios update site.

The P2 mechanism will then download all the dependencies (wst, emf, gef, ...) for you, making the manipulations described by [Pascal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524958/eclipse-3-5-1-galileo-with-ubuntu-9-10-karmic-busted-can-not-install-maven2/2525066#2525066) absolutely not needed.

[alt text http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/331/eclipsem2install.png](http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/331/eclipsem2install.png)

Comment: The problem is that there is a nasty bug with Eclipse 3.5.1 and Linux (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703753/how-do-you-fix-loading-plugins-in-eclipse-3-5-1-on-linux) and I avoid the "contact all update site" when installing plugin (I'm not sure of the faulty update site so I can't disable it).

Comment: @Pascal: I do leave that option checked, but disable almost all update sites except the bare minimum, which usually works (may be not in that exact Linux configuration though).

Comment: It's clearly a good advice and I might adopt this strategy. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

OK - so I got this to work with the following steps:

From Eclipse Menu > Hep > Install New Software > Work With...
Add the following site:
Galileo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo

Now install the following (if not there already):

```
Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
Eclipse Platform
Eclipse Web Developer Tools
Eclipse XML Editors and Tools
Eclipse XSL Developer Tools
JavaScript Developer Tools
Rich Ajax Platform SDK
```

Once that was done, I was able to successfully install Maven through the same process.

I was mainly just fooling around to see if it would work or not.
Some of the above may be redundant or not needed by everyone.

Maybe Pascal's answer is more direct and straightforward.
Anyway, it is working now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember exactly but I think I had to install JEM from Eclipse's Visual Editor [udpate site](http://update.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.0/). But I'm not using the packaged version of Eclipse so I can't certify you won't have to install more stuff. Actually, according to [this page](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DEVNET/Configuring+Eclipse+to+use+the+SDK?focusedCommentId=214860275#comment-214860275), you might have to:

> I had to jump through quite a few
>   hoops to get m2eclipse installed in
>   Eclipse 3.5.1 on Ubuntu 9.10.  I had
>   to install these dependencies in this
>   order:
>
> - JEM from Eclipse's VE package => http://update.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.0/
> - IBM's ICU4J => http://site.icu-project.org/download
> - Eclipse WST => http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/
>     (only org.eclipse.wst.* packages)
>
> before Eclipse would allow me to
>   install m2eclipse. JEM in particular
>   is quite well hidden.

Personally, I [don't recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125819/eclipse-on-ubuntu-do-not-have-jsp-html-and-other-web-files-template/2126125#2126125) using the packaged version though (i.e. I prefer to install it manually).

Comment: Thanks Pascal.  I just managed to get it working.  I'll post the steps I took.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this is to use the synaptic package manager to install maven2 *before* you install m2eclipse using the eclipse installtion manager.  So the steps would be:

1) system->administration->synaptic package manager: check maven2 (and all of its dependencies)

2) eclipse->help->install new software: use http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e and follow the installation directions.

Answer (score 0):

In general when dealing Java tools it's best to install them manually rather than relying on the Linux packaging mechanisms. Java applications typically have their own dependency mechanisms which work better/are better maintained and I find less hassles by not to mixing the two.

Comment: Hmh - interesting.  I was so happy with the apt-get program because it seemed to work so well.  My happiness may be fading a little...  Should this rule be applied to other systems as well, or just Java tools?

Comment: It's not that apt doesn't work well or is not well maintained (quite the opposite), it's that all the packages need to be maintained, and the linux packages do not keep up with the latest java releases. Eclipse and Maven for example have extensive built-in dependency management systems; you really want to take advantage of these instead of relying on apt. For other unix software, apt generally works really well. In any case, as a developer it's a good idea to at least be familiar with how to build and install java and unix tools from source.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Gnome API changes that blocks some SWT widgets from receiving display events. It was fixed in the Eclipse 3.6 code, for older versions just set environment variable GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true.

Comment: This has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Correct Pascal.  This is a different problem, unrelated to non-responsive eclipse buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble when I upgraded to Karmic - the plugin installation dialog was only half-functional. It turned out to be an issue with GDK. There's an easy fix - set  GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1 in your environment. http://blog.export.be/2009/10/fixing-eclipse-for-ubuntu-karmic-koala-9-10/

Comment: Same comment as for @user302783: this has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Correct Pascal. My problem does not have to do with non-responsive eclipse buttons.